# Kronecker quiver and tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, tensor-products, tensors, quiver

Good day, based on representation theory of Assem,

[image]

and the definition of tensor product

[image]

I need to find $\varphi^1_{21}$ and its domain in the kronecker quiver. I did the next:

[image]

but Im confused to find $F_0$ and therefore $F/F_0$ to deduce the domain $\varepsilon _2KQ\varepsilon _1\otimes  \varepsilon _1KQ\varepsilon _1$. Depends it of the field $K$ and of the external operation $ka$, $k\in K, a\in \varepsilon _2KQ\varepsilon _1$?

Comment: Is the first reference from the book of Assem, Simson and Skowroński? If so, it would be better to list all of the authors.

Comment: yes, at the beginning I said it, and the second is Frobenius Algebras I of Skowronski, Kunio.

Comment: You only name Assem.  My comment is that you should name all authors, not only one. (Also, Kunio is Yamagata's first name).

Answer (score 1):

As $\varepsilon_{2}KQ \varepsilon_1 \cong K^2$, $\varepsilon_{i}KQ \varepsilon_i \cong K$, then $\varphi_{21}^1:K^2 \otimes K\rightarrow K^2$ and for properties of tensor product  $K^2 \otimes K\cong K^2.$